# AWS CLI: Key is not in valid OpenSSH public key format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How to solve this?

```bash
# I used this command to create the key with a password
$ ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -C "awsfrankfurt" -f ~/.ssh/awsfrankfurt

# Then when I try to import it into AWS EC2, the error appears:
$ aws --region eu-central-1 ec2 import-key-pair \
    --key-name "awsfrankfurt" \
    --public-key-material ~/.ssh/awsfrankfurt

An error occurred (InvalidKey.Format) when the ImportKeyPair operation: 
Key is not in valid OpenSSH public key format
```

Comment: [julian-alarcon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7820857) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68836059) saying "Starting yesterday, AWS EC2 supports Ed25519 SSH Keys! [https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/08/amazon-ec2-customers-ed25519-keys-authentication/](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/08/amazon-ec2-customers-ed25519-keys-authentication/)"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create your key and then when calling aws's `--public-key-material` argument, call it with `file://` in front of your key path.

**Example:**

```bash
$ aws --region eu-central-1 ec2 import-key-pair \
    --key-name "awsfrankfurt" \
    --public-key-material file://~/.ssh/awsfrankfurt  # <-- this
```

This is a weird issue, because, `file://` prefix is usually used for Windows, but, here with aws, it applies to unix based terminals as well.

Comment: What else could cause the same error message if one prefixes the `file://` before the key path?

Comment: @GusCrawford: Trying to use a non RSA key could also cause the error, see my answer.

Comment: Turns out, with "modern" aws-cli (AWS CLI 2.2.38) what is required is NOT `file://` but `fileb://` (note the 'b').  If the former is used, one still gets the error message in the title of this article. With `fileb://` the key is imported as expected. It's easy to miss if not expecting the 'b'.  It's correct in the doc: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/import-key-pair.html

Answer (score 31):

AWS *only* supports `RSA` keypairs, it does *not* support `DSA`, `ECDSA` or `Ed25519` keypairs. If you try to upload a non `RSA` public key you will get this error.

This is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#how-to-generate-your-own-key-and-import-it-to-aws):

> Amazon EC2 does not accept DSA keys. Make sure your key generator is
>   set up to create RSA keys.

The error message is misleading as you can upload a valid non `RSA` key and get the error:

```
Error import KeyPair: InvalidKey.Format: Key is not in valid OpenSSH public key format
```

This answer should be useful for people who find this page after searching for this error message.

Comment: Isn't that what the asker has created, an RSA key?

Comment: It is. My answer is directed at people who get to this page when googling the error message (as stated on the final line). Thanks to google there are times when the majority of people who get to a SO page are interested in the answer to a different problem rather than the stated question, this is one of those times.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same situation when I was creating an aws keypair using pulumi. Strangely, it worked when I used the content of the public key rather than the .pub file.

So here is what I changed in my code.

from :

```
aws.ec2.KeyPair("keypair", public_key="~/.ssh/mykey.pub")
```

to:

```
aws.ec2.KeyPair("keypair", public_key="ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQC9u37J5tfzmeA8INBCcFSPKnUN8GIjYFdPOOCn8AjUC5iTJX/7TWd3pZ42Z++RCIlvBvKkH7LL1p"
```

Changed from path to .pub file to the content of .pub file